# Coinciding actions in the past

Tags: formal-language

I have a question: 
It is correct to say " I was doing x when y happened" 
Also it is correct to say " While I was doing x, y happened" 
BUT is it right to say " When I was doing x, y happened "
In other words, when an action happens during another action in progress, can we bring "when" before the progressive tense or we can only say "while" or "as" before it?

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly idiomatic to say

> When I was travelling in France, I met this really interesting Swiss historian.

It means the same as, but is **perhaps** a little less formal than,

> While I was travelling in France, I met this really interesting Swiss historian.